# Maximum Upload Speed to SharePoint Online?

Tags: file-upload

I've got a symmetrical 170Mbps connection, speedtest around 168/169. I can hit these numbers quite nicely in real life, I just attempted an upload to my google drive and hit 165Mbps for at least 30 seconds.

However, my upload to SharePoint is terrible.

It seems to cap out around 7Mbps for the upload speed. Doesn't matter if I'm using the browser upload, windows explorer, powershell bulk upload, or Sync(OneDrive for Business)

Does anyone get more than this?

I googled and found articles about changing registry values for WinSock rates (no effect) and using Fiddler (no effect)

I'm also going to file a ticket with Microsoft, but anyone have any other thoughts?

Comment: Check here: http://o365datacentermap.azurewebsites.net/ Does that match your timezone in o365

Comment: I'm not sure what timezone you're referring to on that site. I'm Pacific, and the O365 data center I'm uploading to is going to be the same, either Seattle or San Jose. I'm close enough to any american center though that it shouldn't significantly affect upload speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked this exact question a while ago to MS Support. Their answer is you should expect a throughput of 0,75 GB/hour due to bandwith throttling, the CSOM, virusscanning, replication of data etc.

In practice you can reach higher speeds depending on the time of the day. 1 big file will also be processed faster than thousands of small files due to the HTTP-requests-overhead.
Microsoft doesn't guarantee any performance on Office 365.

If you're trying to migrate (a lot of) data from on-premise to SharePoint on-line you might want to look into the Migration API:

- [SharePoint Online Migration API User Guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-Migration-API-User-Guide-555049c6-15ef-45a6-9a1f-a1ef673b867c)
- [SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business Migration Speed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-Migration-Speed-21cfb6a0-fa4c-44c6-9a39-0f45e85e371f)

Comment: Just tested file upload through CSOM today. I get around 10 GB through per hour.

Answer (score 1):

New to SharePoint Online and just experienced this issue moving 55GB of data to a new Library. Using Explorer view, transfer rate slowly maxed out at 145KB/sec. Using IE11 transfer was equally slow. Using Chrome however, and dragging folders from Explorer to Library in Chrome (NOT using the Upload feature), transfer rate is at least 10x faster. Don't know why, and while it's true right at this moment, an update to Chrome, Windows, or SPO may change it anytime.

Answer (score -2):

Can you double check the following:

1. What is the latency to your SharePoint Online system?
   open a cmd window and enter
   ping [sharepoint online fqdn]
2. Does Google drive use parallel connections?

   start an upload request using google drive (for multiple documents of course) and then in the cmd window enter ping [google drive fqdn]
   This is necessary to get the IP address then in the same cmd window enter
   netstat -ano
   How many TCP connections do you see to the Google drive's IP address?

I have also done bulk uploads to SharePoint Online and reached levels of about 40 Mbps on my 50 Mbps link. This was with a tool that uses 6 parallel connections to upload to SharePoint.

Paul

Comment: What tool were you using? I don't think SharePoint uses parallel connections by default. 6 x 7 = 42, so that would make sense.

Comment: sorry for slow response. I have build a browser-based tool that uses JavaScript and is multi-threaded. The tool is name SLIM Companion.